# Deploy Webservice Asmx on IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

I read many articles to deploy web service on IIS7. So what I do is:

1. Go to IIS Manager
2. Add Virtual Directory
3. Physical path I get

[image]

4. Click Add
5. When I browse the virtual directory it gives me Error 500

[image]

6. Then I go to Application Pool and select .NET v4.5 and go to Advance Setting and change Identity under Process Model to Current Account from ApplicationPoolIdentity.
7. Instead of Virtual Directory I add new application with Alias Math and Application Pool .NET v4.5
8. When I browse after restart the default site I receive error 503 Service Not Available.

Web Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Pleas help.

Comment: There is no web.config in the folder you selected. There is another WebService folder inside the folder you selected. You need to point your virtual directory to that folder.

Comment: I update my question with web.config file, how I point virtual director. And no need of add new application?

Comment: How did you create new virtual directory at first place? You need to select that virtual directory in iis and selct advance properties of it that's where you can change the path of the virtual directory.https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754640(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I add the path where web.config is located but now I face the error "   Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
" I go to Default Site -> Authorization -> Anonymous Authorization and add "IUSR" but still problem not solved

Comment: Now my path is like "C:\Users\SalmanMushtaq\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebService\WebService" as per your link @ChetanRanpariya